# Writer txt file that have maximum of lines

Tags: c#, algorithm, oop

I want to create a txt file that have maximum of 400 numbers of lines. If the text file reached to the maximum of lines then a new file will be created with different name, same case applies if the limit is reached again.

I wrote a class 'MaxLinesWriter', but it works very slow, not fast like the original streamer.

Can somebody help me?

```
public class MaxLinesWriter
{
    private int n = 0;
    public int MaxLines;
    public string NameFile;
    private string ConstNameFile;
    public int CounterOfLines;

    DateTime date = new DateTime();

    public MaxLinesWriter(string NameFileInput, int MaxLinesInput)
    {
        MaxLines = MaxLinesInput;
        ConstNameFile = NameFileInput;
        NameFile = ConstNameFile + date.Hour.ToString() + date.Minute.ToString() + date.Second.ToString() + date.Millisecond.ToString();
        CounterOfLines = 0;
    }

    public void WriteLine(object StringToWrite)
    {
        if (CounterOfLines < MaxLines)
        {
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(NameFile + ".txt", true);
            writer.WriteLine(StringToWrite);
            CounterOfLines++;
            writer.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            CounterOfLines = 1;
            date = date.AddMilliseconds(1);
            NameFile = ConstNameFile + date.Hour.ToString() + date.Minute.ToString() + date.Second.ToString() + date.Millisecond.ToString();
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(NameFile + ".txt");
            writer.WriteLine(StringToWrite);
            writer.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: opening a StreamWriter for each line seems to be your problem here. try carrying it outside of the WriteLine function and add it to your class as an attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you calling WriteLine() method in an iteration initialize `StreamWriter` out of your iteration:

```
public class MaxLinesWriter
{
    private int n = 0;
    public int MaxLines;
    public string NameFile;
    private string ConstNameFile;
    public int CounterOfLines;
    private StreamWriter writer;

    DateTime date = new DateTime();

    public MaxLinesWriter(string NameFileInput, int MaxLinesInput)
    {
        MaxLines = MaxLinesInput;
        ConstNameFile = NameFileInput;
        NameFile = ConstNameFile + date.Hour.ToString() + date.Minute.ToString() + date.Second.ToString() + date.Millisecond.ToString();
        CounterOfLines = 0;
        writer = new StreamWriter(NameFile + ".txt", true);
    }

    public void WriteLine(object StringToWrite)
    {
        if (CounterOfLines < MaxLines)
        {
            writer.WriteLine(StringToWrite);
            CounterOfLines++;

        }
        else
        {
            writer.Close();
            CounterOfLines = 1;
            date = date.AddMilliseconds(1);
            NameFile = ConstNameFile + date.Hour.ToString() + date.Minute.ToString() + date.Second.ToString() + date.Millisecond.ToString();
            writer = new StreamWriter(NameFile + ".txt");
            writer.WriteLine(StringToWrite);
        }
    }

    // Call it after your last data
    public void Close()
    {
         writer.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey ali, thanks. but it does'n working. I tried this.

Comment: @AnnaBokovskaya: What was the problem?

Comment: @AnnaBokovskaya: Compiling error or Exception? What kind of exception or error?

Comment: Compeling for example:               MaxLinesWriter writer = new MaxLinesWriter("example2", 2);
            writer.WriteLine("hey");
            writer.WriteLine("this");
            writer.WriteLine("is");
            writer.WriteLine("working");
            writer.WriteLine("ok");

Comment: @AnnaBokovskaya: I edited my code and write all of your required code for MaxLineWriters class. try it.

Comment: it works!! thanks. but every text file the maximum lines is 13324.

Comment: @AnnaBokovskaya: If this works slow for 13324 maximum lines, you can gather all of your numbers in a List or StringBuilder and finally you write it in a file. Do you want more information about it?

Comment: You need to add a `Dispose` method (or at least a `Close` method) so that the file can be closed before the program ends. Otherwise, stuff that's written to the output buffer won't be flushed to the file.

Answer (score 1):

@Ali Sepehri.Kh
The writer will be closed at the end of the constructor. You should set `leaveOpen` to true to avoid this.

BTW, setting a bigger buffer should also help.

This should work (tested):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace TEST
{
    class Program
    {
        public class MaxLinesWriter
        {
            public int MaxLines;
            public string NameFile;
            private string ConstNameFile;
            public int CounterOfLines;
            private FileStream st;
            private StreamWriter writer;

            DateTime date = new DateTime();

            public MaxLinesWriter(string NameFileInput, int MaxLinesInput)
            {
                MaxLines = MaxLinesInput;
                ConstNameFile = NameFileInput;
                NameFile = ConstNameFile + date.Hour.ToString() + date.Minute.ToString() + date.Second.ToString() + date.Millisecond.ToString();
                CounterOfLines = 0;
                st = new FileStream(NameFile + ".txt", FileMode.CreateNew);
                writer = new StreamWriter(st, Encoding.UTF8, 10240, true);
            }

            public void WriteLine(object StringToWrite)
            {

                if (CounterOfLines < MaxLines)
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(StringToWrite);
                    CounterOfLines++;
                }
                else
                {
                    CounterOfLines = 1;
                    date = date.AddMilliseconds(1);
                    NameFile = ConstNameFile + date.Hour.ToString() + date.Minute.ToString() + date.Second.ToString() + date.Millisecond.ToString();

                    st = new FileStream(NameFile + ".txt", FileMode.CreateNew);
                    writer = new StreamWriter(st, Encoding.UTF8, 10240, true);

                    writer.WriteLine(StringToWrite);

                }
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MaxLinesWriter mx = new MaxLinesWriter("test", 10000);

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
                mx.WriteLine("Hello World");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hey, i tried this and it's not working. MaxLinesWriter writer =  new MaxLinesWriter("example", 2);
            writer.WriteLine("hey");
            writer.WriteLine("this");
            writer.WriteLine("is");
            writer.WriteLine("working");
            writer.WriteLine("ok"); //it send me an error

Comment: I think you must have missed something. I've pasted a complete copy of my code. It runs properly here in my VS2013.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
public class MaxLinesWriter
{
    private int n = 0;
    public int MaxLines;
    public string NameFile;
    private string ConstNameFile;
    public int CounterOfLines;
    private StreamWriter writer;
    DateTime date = new DateTime();

    public MaxLinesWriter(string NameFileInput, int MaxLinesInput)
    {
        MaxLines = MaxLinesInput;
        ConstNameFile = NameFileInput;
        NameFile = ConstNameFile + date.Hour.ToString() + date.Minute.ToString() + date.Second.ToString() + date.Millisecond.ToString();
        CounterOfLines = 0;
        writer = new StreamWriter(NameFile + ".txt", true);
    }

    public void WriteLine(object StringToWrite)
    {
        if (CounterOfLines < MaxLines)
        {
            writer.WriteLine(StringToWrite);
            CounterOfLines++;
            writer.Flush();
        }
        else
        {
            CounterOfLines = 1;
            date = date.AddMilliseconds(1);
            NameFile = ConstNameFile + date.Hour.ToString() + date.Minute.ToString() + date.Second.ToString() + date.Millisecond.ToString();
            writer = new StreamWriter(NameFile + ".txt", true);
            writer.WriteLine(StringToWrite);
            writer.Flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it does't create any new txt files. it just write to one file.

Comment: I have edited answer, try that. And also check its performance

Comment: It works!! thanks. but every text file the maximum lines is 13324.